# How can I check the number of line feeds in a string?

Tags: c#

I have a field that I use to hold text. I am going to hold the text in a HTML textarea but I need to set the number of lines.

How can I count the number of line feeds in a string so I can set the textarea rows?

Comment: It's just at the start when the textarea is being set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line break is one or two characters, depending on the system. On a windows system it's the two character combination `\r\n`, but you can look for only one of them when counting them.

As a string is enumerable, you can use the `Count` extension method:

```
int cnt = str.Count(c => c == '\n');
```

Comment: I would have opted for `\n` over `\r` because I think generally systems use either `\r\n` or `\n`. But that is just what I have noticed, I don't know enough to be sure of that

Comment: \n is the safer bet: The only semi-modern system to use a single \r was MacOS 9. OSX moved to \n. Checking for \r is of limited value and you'll miss more things than you'll catch, assuming your text files come from arbitrary systems.

Comment: Good point, I changed it to \n as it's generally more useful. Getting the first character from Environment.Newline would also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Using `LINQ`:

```
int lineCount = text.Count(c => c == '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code extension method.

```
public class static Extension
{
    public static int CountStringOccurrences(this string text, string pattern)
        {
        // Loop through all instances of the string 'text'.
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while ((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i)) != -1)
        {
            i += pattern.Length;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
        }
}
```

Use

```
var text = "Sam dfdfgdf Sam.";
text.CountStringOccurrences("Sam"));
```

Comment: That's not an extension method ;)

Comment: I'm really looking for just a few lines of inline code to count line feeds :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
int lines = stringVariable.Split('\n').Length + 1;
```

Or, you could use [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx):

```
int lines = stringVariable.Count(s => s == '\n') + 1;
```

(both of these examples assume that your string doesn't contain a trailing newline.)

However, this won't necessarily give you what you need if any of your rows of text are wider than your `textarea`, since their text will wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex

```
int count =  new Regex(@"\n").Matches(inputstr).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way;

```
 int lines = str.Length - str.Replace("\n", "").Length;
```

Answer (score -1):

It will depend on the number of cols in the text area. Try something like this:

```
StringBuilder mystring = new StringBuilder(@"Hey this is a fairly long string which I used in this /
example to show how long strings might be broken up into different lines based on how  /
wide your text area is. What is going to happen is we are about to insert a newline  /
after however many characters the textarea is wide. We'll also count the number of   /
newlines that we put in, and that number plus one will be the number we need for the  /
textarea!");

int columnCounter = 0;
int lineCounter= 1; //1 for the first line
const int COLUMNS_IN_TEXT_AREA = howeverManyColsYouHave;
for(int i = 0; i<mystring.Length;i++) //set to less than mystring.length, just in case the string were really short.
{
    if(columnCounter >= COLUMNS_IN_TEXTAREA)
    {
        mystring.Insert(i,"\n");
        lineCounter ++;
    }
}
```

now send the stringbuilder and line count as JSon or something to your view and voila!